# Can an infant be burped when sleeping?

Tags: sleep, food, milk

I understand that infants need assistance to be burped when awake. My question is if an infant is fed and then falls asleep, should you attempt to burp them while they are sleeping? Will they burp if they are sleeping? I have tried burping my infant soon after he doses off and have never gotten a burp out of him. My concern is that if I place him to sleep, he will eventually get gas that will wake him up. Should he be awakened to be burped before going to sleep?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you are concerned that your infant does not always burp after eating.  It was once thought that burping was necessary, but thinking is changing about that.  Burping may help some infants, but it is not required for all infants all the time.

> So, if you try to burp your baby and nothing happens, no need to worry. If you don't burp your baby ever, no need to worry. If your baby is spitting up or has colic, burping may not make those any better, or may make it worse. And remember, your pediatrician is the best resource for any concerns you may have about your baby's digestive system.

[Debunking Old Wives' Tales: Do Babies Need to Burp After Feeding?](https://healthcare.utah.edu/the-scope/shows.php?shows=0_j8jqtr2m) (Dr. Cindy Gellner, University of Utah Health)

Comment: `your pediatrician is the best resource`, I doubt this. The baby is the best resource.